# Trigonometry Functions/equations

Tags: trigonometry

Given that $\sin A=\dfrac{8}{17},\;$ find the possible values of $\cos A$ and $\cot A$.

Can someone please explain this question? I' new to the topic, and I'm very unsure as to how its done.thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, $\sin^2A+\cos^2A=1$; this is the [Pythagorean theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem#Pythagorean_trigonometric_identity).
So you know two possible values of $\cos A$. Hence you can deduce the possible values of $\cot A$.

> Answer: $\cos A=\pm\sqrt{1-(8/17)^2}=\pm15/17$. Hence $\cot A=\pm15/8$.

Hope this helps.

Comment: May I ask how did you get cot?

Comment: $\cot A=\cos A/\sin A$. I think this is the definition.

Answer (score 1):

Another method that might be easier would be to draw a picture.  Recalling that $\sin{A} = \frac{\text{opposite}}{\text{adjacent}}$, you would draw a right triangle with hypotenuse $17$, one side of length $8$, and use the pythagorean theorem to find the length of the other side (it happens to be $15$).  The angle $A$ is opposite to the side of length $8$, and thus adjacent to the side of length $15$, so that $\cos{A} = \frac{15}{17}$.  Drawing the picture in a Cartesian plane you'd notice a length of $\pm 15$ would work for the adjacent side, so that you would have $\cos{A} = \pm \frac{15}{17}$.  Then the definition of $\cot{A} = \frac{1}{\tan{A}} = \frac{\text{adjacent}}{\text{opposite}}$ would give you your answer.